# Mysql - Most recent timestamp multiple records

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return the Task that has a note linked to it with the most recent timestamp. Although this query works, it's not returning the most recent timestamp consistently. Is there another method to doing this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  tasks.TaskID, tasks.desc, tasks.startdate, tasks.active, notes.note,          max(notes.NoteDate) 
FROM tasks INNER JOIN notes ON tasks.TaskID=notes.NoteID 
WHERE notes.NoteDate >= curdate() 
GROUP BY tasks.TaskID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT tasks.TaskID, tasks.desc, tasks.startdate, tasks.active, notes.note,          notes.NoteDate
FROM tasks INNER JOIN notes ON tasks.TaskID=notes.NoteID 
order by NoteDate Desc 
limit 1
```

Update, if you want more than one row (for example where notedate in last day):

```
SELECT tasks.TaskID, tasks.desc, tasks.startdate, tasks.active, notes.note,          notes.NoteDate
FROM tasks INNER JOIN notes ON tasks.TaskID=notes.NoteID 
where notes.NoteDate > date_sub(current_date(),interval 1 day)
order by NoteDate Desc
```

Comment: The problem with that is I'm trying to return multiple records, not just one. I need a list of ALL the tasks that were most recently updated.

Comment: what does most recently mean ?

Comment: Updated today, if that helps. So I want a list of tasks that have had notes added today. Also, the NoteID is a timestamp field and not just a date.